# libpam with google authenticator not working on 16.04 with home encryption

Tags: login, encryption, lightdm, authentication

I have installed 16.04.2 on my system and enabled 2FA login by this [howto](https://www.howtogeek.com/208205/how-to-use-two-factor-authentication-on-your-linux-desktop-with-google-authenticator/)

I have installed the required package by

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
```

Then generated the key by

```
google-authenticator
```

Edited lightdm by

```
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

Added

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/var/unencrypted/${USER}/.google_authenticator
```

as the last line of the file then saved. ([Source](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam))

Then created the directory structure by

```
sudo mkdir /var/unencrypted/${USER}/
```

then

```
cd
```

after that

```
sudo cp .google_authenticator /var/unencrypted/${USER}/
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 777 unencrypted
```

But it says at the next login "Invalid password" (so it doesn't ask for a OTP code). Without the line at the lightdm config everything is fine (I mean I can successfully login but without 2FA).

What do I do wrong?

Thanks,
Armand

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing some problems too with this

Comment: by the way, as described in the doc you should use `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so user=root secret=/usr/share/google-auth/${USER}/.google_authenticator` to enforce the use of user root for the lookup, and `chown root:root $file` and `chmod 400 $file`